# How to use mdc-select (Material design components) in combination with Aurelia

Tags: material-design, aurelia

At this moment I'm working on a project where we use [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) in combination with [Material Design Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web). Because the project is fairly new, we are using MDC version 0.13.

We are using multiple select fields and some of them should have an initial value, like the snippet below:

```html
<select value.bind="_PersonID" class="mdc-select mdc-list-item__end-detail">
  <option model.bind="null">Select person</option>
  <option repeat.for="person of Persons" model.bind="person.ID">${person.Name}</option>
</select>
```

This works great and like we expected it to work. But now we want this kind of behavior with the mdc-select [structure & styling](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select). For that we use the following:

```html
<div mdc-select role="listbox" class="mdc-select mdc-list-item__end-detail">
  <span class="mdc-select__selected-text">????</span>
  <div class="mdc-simple-menu mdc-select__menu">
    <ul class="mdc-list mdc-simple-menu__items">
      <li class="mdc-list-item" role="option" repeat.for="person of Persons" model.bind="person.ID">${person.Name}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this piece is that we've only a "CurrentPersonId". But we have to define the name in the  tag. In the documentation of MDC, it also declares an "aria-selected" attribute in the li. When we put that on the li tag, it won't update the span on init.